# how to mark polarities to write loop equations

Tags: circuit-analysis, polarity

Need a help to mark polarities to get loop equations or any other method get equations without marking polarities.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDNSc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what little you write, but more importantly, you say you "need help", but show no effort or own research. Which is a no-no to begin with, but specially so for what looks like it might be a homework question.

Comment: I tried and got some equations and I don't  know those right or wrong. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Passive sign convention, polarities are according to following scheme:

[image: Passive Sign Convention]

Assuming directions of currents as in following images, we'll write following polarities while writing equations for different loops.

**Loop 1:**
[image: For I1]

**Equation:**
$$
    I_{1}R_{2} + (I_{1}-I_{2})R_{5} +(I_{1}-I_{3})(\frac{1}{sC_{1}} + R_{1}) = 0
$$

**Loop 2:**
[image: For I2]
**Equation:**
$$
I_{2}R_{4} + I_{2}\times{sL_{4}} + (I_{2}-I_{3})R_{3} +(I_{2}-I_{1})R_{5}=0
$$
**Loop 3:**
[image: For I3]
**Equation:**
$$
(I_{3}-I_{1})(\frac{1}{sC_{1}} + R_{1}) +(I_{3}-I_{2})R_{3}=E\times{sin(\omega t)}
$$

Comment: You're most welcome. :)

Comment: We prefer not to supply complete homework answers to users - especially when they show no effort at a solution as in this case. Note that you don't have to take screen-grabs from CircuitLab schematics. You can save them directly into the post (and edit them later, if you need to).

Comment: @Transistor Got it. Thanks for the tips and advice. :)